# Linker removes unreferenced code

Tags: c++, linker

I'm currently working on a modular project and some of our systems won't work, I'll try to explain what we're trying to do.

We've got a main project that is extended by a number of modules (dlls), these modules can have bootstrapper code that will register itself before the main loop starts. It will register itself using our bootstrapping system, however the problem for us is that the modules will not register itself unless we specifically call a function from said modules. We think this is because the linker removes unreferenced code as part of optimizations (this also happens in debug mode).

The main function is set up as follows:

```
#include <bootstrap/bootstrapper.hpp>
#include <module/module.hpp>

int main()
{
    // foo is an empty function in the module header file
    foo(); // if I were to remove this empty function, 
           // the modules bootstrapping code will not execute
    return fade::bootstrap::run();
}
```

without the `foo()` function the bootstrapping code doesn't get executed

```
void foo()
{

}

namespace
{
    std::unique_ptr<game> game_;
    FADE_BOOTSTRAP_MODULE(module_game) // registers itself to the bootstrapper
}
```

We've tried a number of things such as the linker options:

- /INCLUDE
- /OPT:NOREF
- /EXPORT

But to no avail, either it gives us undefined symbol errors or it does nothing at all.

Is there anything we can do so that the unreferenced code doesn't get optimized away? We want to keep our project modular and cross platform so we'd rather not hardcode any solutions to our main function.

Comment: I'm not sure it is optimized away. It's a global variable that can only be initialized when the dll is loaded (as opposed to when the main executable is loaded). If no code is called in the dll, the global will not be initialized, and neither will any related code be called. You must remember that the main executable must itself load dlls (either explicitly or not).

Comment: So for every module we use we should call a function like `foo()` or manually load the library using `LoadLibrary("libraryname.dll")`? Because both work, but as our project is modular we don't want to hardcode module specific code. (And loadlibrary is also platform specific, so that's a definite no go for us)

Comment: Yes. A dll (or shared library) cannot load itself, how would it know what to load against!? I suggest you write a "loading module" that reads some sort of manifest file for the libraries to load. It will than call the platform specific code (conditional compilation and other techniques) to load the various libraries.

Comment: As there's no other way around this seems to be the best solution thank you very much @StoryTeller